# GNU Octave 4 GUI not working properly with Windows 10

Tags: windows, octave

GNU Octave 4.0.0 used to run well on my Sony VAIO with Windows 7.  However, after I upgraded to Windows 10, I couldn't get the GUI to start up at all.  (The text/CLI mode still worked though.)  I also tried Octave 4.0.1 and 4.0.2, but they had the same problem.  Did someone run into similar problems before?  Is there a way to get around it?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you see an error or what happens?

Comment: @Andy Yes, Andy, the usual error diaolog box opened up, saying "octave-gui.exe has stopped working. A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available."

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find a way to get around this problem.  I'll share it here, in case other people also run into it.  The GUI opened up successfully, after I clicked the "Disable dispaly scaling on high DPI settings" checkbox under the "Compatibility" tab of octave-4.0.2.exe.